# Make jQuery equal heights script recalculate with new content

Tags: jquery

I'm using [this jQuery plugin](http://www.jainaewen.com/files/javascript/jquery/equal-height-columns.html) to get the main content and sidebar to match heights—which works fine. But I am now updating a member directory page, and I've set up the names to expand from a basic listing to a full listing when they are clicked. However, I can't get the content and sidebar divs to expand and contract with them.

Here's a sample page with dummy content: http://stylesmithonline.com/AWAD_test/AWAD_directory_test.html (Note: I know I need to move those onClick events to their own function—someone else created the original site, so I've got some cleaning to do).

I tried adding the class "expand" to the links and calling on the function with this:

```
$(document).delegate('.expand', 'click', function(){
$("#content, #sidebar, #content-sidebar-wrap").equalHeightColumns();
});
```

It works one time if I remove the original call to the function:

```
$(window).load(function() {
$("#content, #sidebar, #content-sidebar-wrap").equalHeightColumns();
});
```

Also, if I pass in a specific height to the click event, it will work.

Any idea why it's not expanding and contracting the way I want it to?

Thanks,
Scott

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the documentation, I believe it's not working because the height is set by reading the height of the div. Your main div, however, has a height set by the plugin already, and this doesn't change when more content is added.

Try resetting the height of your divs to `auto` before calling the plugin:

```
$("#content, #sidebar, #content-sidebar-wrap").css('height','auto').equalHeightColumns();
```

Also, if you're trying to match heights because of the white background, allow me to suggest an alternative: use the [Faux Columns](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/) technique. Could save you many headaches.

Comment: I'm aware of it. But this is a responsive layout (in progress), so both columns narrow and the sidebar drops below the main content at a certain point. Further, faux columns wouldn't allow for the halftone pattern between the columns.

Comment: Would a transparent PNG work to reveal the background pattern? I see your point about responsive design, however, and it's a very good one.

Comment: I thought that too. But if I add `height: 300`, for example, into the click function, it does overwrite the height set by the initial run of the plugin. Hmmm...I think you're on the right track though. Perhaps that works because it's a specific value. Anyway, I tried setting it to auto, but that didn't work.

Comment: Looking at firebug, I can see that it is, of course, adding the height inline. So, I think you're right. The next time I call the function, it sees that they're set to the same height already. So, I guess I need to remove that styling on click first...

Comment: I misunderstood. I thought you meant that I should set height to auto in my style sheet. Duh. I RESET it like you said and it works! Thank you! To clarify for those searching: `$(document).delegate('.expand', 'click', function(){
   $('#content, #sidebar, #content-sidebar-wrap').css('height' , 'auto');
            $("#content, #sidebar, #content-sidebar-wrap").equalHeightColumns();
        });`

Comment: Good to hear! I edited my answer so the correct part's closer up.